# Magento Mobile Website Register Button Disabled

Tags: php, magento, mobile, magento-1.7

In my magento mobile website registration on checkout button disappear but on desktop website it appears.

I have disabled the guest checkout on my magento website.

I have also tried by placing button it will affect the default steps working.

I have also tried on default magento but still i am getting same on default magento.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add below code after the line no 104 in 
app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.php

```
  <button id="onepage-guest-register-button" type="button" class="button" onclick="checkout.setMethod();"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>
```

below the

```
<input type="hidden" name="checkout_method" id="login:register" value="register" checked="checked" />
```

the final code look like this

```
  <button id="onepage-guest-register-button" type="button" class="button" onclick="checkout.setMethod();"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the Css property for the button.
It may be hidden in the mobile view.
or else tell the site in which you face the error.

Comment: i have already checked with the css and other things i think it is bug of magento for mobile website.